# Problem after update: blue screen with only the mouse cursor

Tags: 12.04, updates, gtk

My Ubuntu 12.04 was normally updated through the Update Manager, something about gtk. Then I rebooted and now all that shows after the splash screen is a blue screen that only shows the cursor.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same issue. After a lot of painful efforts, solved the problem in my box.

Doing the below steps fixed the problem in my machine:

```
* press ctrl+alt+f1 and login as root in the tty1
* cd /usr/lib/*arch-name*/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/
* find *some-version-number*/loaders/ > ~/pixbuf-files
  *(not the pkg-version,try ls cmd,only one dir would list out)*
* vim ~/pixbuf-files and delete 1st line
* cat ~/pixbuf-files | xargs -n1  gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > *the-version-number-in-step-3*/loaders.cache 
* reboot
```

in my case:

```
* press ctrl+alt+f1 and login as root in the tty1
* cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/
* find 2.10.0/loaders/ > ~/pixbuf-files
* vim ~/pixbuf-files and delete 1st line
* cat ~/pixbuf-files | xargs -n1  gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > 2.10.0/loaders.cache 
* reboot
```

Comment: last command fails with `xargs: gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: No such file or directory`. please help!

Comment: OK, you just have to make sure that it is installed: `apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem is that I am very new to gnu / linux and i do not understand anything you say about how to solve the problem. Is there any way to report this problem to canonical?

Comment: Wow such a great answer! My apt-get installation failed with suggestion to run another command (I believe it was with flags - - configure - a) after this completed, i was able to install libgdk package and was able to run the last command. Afterwards reboot worked perfectly

Comment: Just to clarify the command is 'dpkg - - configure - a'