# Recent Update Issue

Tags: unity, updates, troubleshooting, debug

I updated my Ubuntu 12.04 server yesterday with the latest updates and now when Ubuntu starts it is in a really strange state.  A purple screen comes up but there are no Unity icons and I can't really do anything, there are no errors that I can detect.

I've never really had any issues like this with Ubuntu so I'm a bit unsure how to get it resolved, my Linux commannd line knowlege is somewhat limited so any details would be greatly appreciated in attempting to debug.

Is there any way to rollback recent updates?  Does anyone have any suggestions for troubleshoting or have any ideas on what could be the issue?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Pls see if the other question's answer helps:

[http://askubuntu.com/questions/435623/problem-after-update-blue-screen-with-only-the-mouse-cursor][1] 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/435623/problem-after-update-blue-screen-with-only-the-mouse-cursor

Comment: Thanks for the help, the following link did correct my issue:
http://askubuntu.com/q/435623/259557

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/435623/259557 followed the steps in this post and it resolved the issue