# Ubuntu 13.10 unity not loading

Tags: unity, 13.10

Ok. Here's the situation. The only thing that will load is the wallpaper and the icons I had on my desktop. The launcher on the left dos not load, and the taskbar on the top does not load. The final things I did on my Laptop before unity died that I remember are as such: uninstalled libreoffice 4.2 so I could install 4.2.2, installed adobe flash player, installed (i think its called) gimp photo editor, installed gnash. Icons started dissapearing off my left side launcher that i had locked to it, the terminal would not led me cd to the libre 4.2.2 folder. the spotify icon became a question mark. my home folder crashed randomly. my backup failed. so i restarted my pc. when it came to the log on screen it did not show me the option to change desktop enviroments (gnome fallback, unity, etc) and when i logged on all thats there is my background and the desktop icons i had on it. steam is just a white square. I need to install libre. and i need my computer to work for school tomorrow. Please help me to get my pc to work
PS i installed that tool to change graphic settings to see if i could enable the unity plugin but i could not find it. I think its called something like ccsm or something like that. it did not work. Help please

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the post below described how to make sure the unity plugin is enabled, it may help with what you're seeinh

[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-)
load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: A recent update on 12.04 had a similar issue you may want to look at ad well.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/435623/problem-after-update-blue-screen-with-only-the-mouse-cursor