# Ubuntu 12.04 - Problem with Chrome & Chromium since last update

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, chromium

Two days ago, Update Manager said there were several pending updates. Which I didn't check (my bad) and just went for it. Left it updating all night. Next day after rebooting, Gnome Desktop wouldn't show wallpapers nor icons.

This helped me with THAT issue: [Problem after update: blue screen with only the mouse cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435623/problem-after-update-blue-screen-with-only-the-mouse-cursor)

But then I started using Chrome, and it just hangs/freezes after a while.
Have reinstalled it several times (remove, purge, delete ./config files, etc)
Also, tried Chromium with the same result!

My best guess, it's a problem with ATI video driver.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA   
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC410 [Radeon Xpress 200/1100]
```

Which could be not working properly with the current (updated) kernel.

```
$ uname -a
Linux smarthost 3.8.0-37-generic #53~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 19 21:37:54 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But I've tried login with latter Kernel from GRUB, with same result.
So I think maybe the update, also updated the driver (or something similar).

My motherboard is Intel D102GGC2 with ATI Radeon Xpress 200 video. So I downloaded proper driver for it at: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy1&os=Linux%20x86_64

But couldn't install it, because of this:

```
==================================================
 ATI Technologies Linux Driver Installer/Packager 
==================================================

Error: ./default_policy.sh does not support version
default:v2:x86_64:lib32::none:3.8.0-37-generic; make sure that the version is being
correctly set by --iscurrentdistro

Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.ejUbLW
-------
```

So I'm stuck using Firefox which is terrible slow!
Any ideas anybody? Suggestions are welcome!

--- EDIT ---

When running Chrome from command line (terminal) and browsing nothing more than Google's homepage, I get this error in less than 5 minutes:

```
$ /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --disable-gpu
[18793:18793:0324/110657:ERROR:profile_sync_service.cc(1311)] History Delete Directives datatype error was encountered: Delete directives not supported with encryption.
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
[18793:18817:0324/111221:ERROR:native_backend_gnome_x.cc(475)] Keyring find failed: Error al comunicarse con gnome-keyring-daemon
Killed
```

On @saiarcot895's clue about using Google Sync... I opened Chrome once again from command line and tried to unsync my account. And as soon as I clic on the button to unlink my account, I get this other error:

```
$ /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --disable-gpu
[21573:21573:0324/140022:ERROR:profile_sync_service.cc(1311)] History Delete Directives datatype error was encountered: Delete directives not supported with encryption.
[21573:21615:0324/140023:ERROR:download.cc(356)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
Killed
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same thing but with a nvidia g-card. So that implies it has nothing to do with the ati driver.

Comment: What is the output if you run Chromium/Google Chrome in Terminal? Also, try the `--disable-gpu` flag to confirm that it is a problem with the GPU/GPU drivers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @saiarcot895.
Following your advice and while having just www.google.com opened (not browsing)... after 5 minutes, I got this :

$ /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --disable-gpu
[18793:18793:0324/110657:ERROR:profile_sync_service.cc(1311)] History Delete Directives datatype error was encountered: Delete directives not supported with encryption.
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
[18793:18817:0324/111221:ERROR:native_backend_gnome_x.cc(475)] Keyring find failed: Error al comunicarse con gnome-keyring-daemon

Comment: Can you edit your main question and paste the output there (to make sure nothing was cut out)? Also, are you using the sync feature?

Comment: Done @saiarcot895. Edited.
Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: After a bit of Googling (and based on this specific error message),  my guess is still on something to do with sync and Gnome Keyring. Can you rename your Chrome configuration folder to back it up (`~/.config/google-chrome`) and reopen Chrome, and see if it crashes?