# Ubuntu 16.04 blue screen with cursor instead of login page

Tags: boot, 16.04, login, shutdown, gui

I was hibernating my laptop as usual from the terminal, but the OS hung and I forced a shutdown by holding down the power button. Now when I turn on my laptop and it loads into a blue screen with a cursor! Sometimes a blinking login form appears. I can use tty.

[image]

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu by a bootable USB, but after loading main page it shows some strange error

> Sorry ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error.

and when I open Datails of the error, the title is:

> ubiguity crashed with dbus.

after I click on continue another error appears:

> the installer encountered an unrecoverable error a desktop session
>   will now be run.

and then graphical environment disappears and switches to tty1.

I want to copy some files from desktop (home directory is encrypted). How can I do that?
How can I solve this problem? And why did this happen?

*My laptop is ASUS n61jv, dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7.*

**Edit:**
I tried startx and now I have a blue screen with a cursor like ×, which I can right click and see menu and I'm able to run programs like firefox with terminal. But I don't see my partitions and personal files  at home directory.

Comment: _“I want to copy some files from desktop (home directory is encrypted).”_ This should be possible to do in console (tty).

Comment: @Melebius I tried to copy home with cp -r to an external USB disk. But the result was some folders named "Downloads", "Desktop", "Music", ... without any content or sub-folder. Then I ran tried ls at home and sub-directories but it returned nothing!

Comment: Follow this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/435623/problem-after-update-blue-screen-with-only-the-mouse-cursor